# OpenCV cv2.imshow display issue

Tags: opencv, object-detection, face-detection

Hi my issue is that I'm detecting faces on my webcam. cv2.imshow() works correctly when there's one face (I use cropping method to display only face). But when there's multiple detections on webcam cv2.imshow() overwrites previous detection and In result there's only one face displayed. Can I apply any for loop to display all detected faces in one window next to each other?

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.